# Enumeration enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm having trouble understanding a question. The question is:
Code a statement that will make the constants in the Terms enumeration available to a class without qualification

This is my code so far;

```
public enum Terms {

    NET_30_DAYS, NET_60_DAYS, NET_90_DAYS; 
    //either name() or super() can be used

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         String s = "Net due " + name() + " days"; 
         return s;
     }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. Take a look at the `import static` statement.

Comment: If it IS homework, and you don't mind being a combative student, let them know that Java advises against this practice: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html (assuming user3928585 is right, and this is what you're trying to accomplish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
import static package.Terms.*;

public class Foo {

     public void aMethod() {
             System.out.println(NET_30_DAYS);
             // you can do the above instead of System.out.println(Terms.NET_30_DAYS);
     }
}
```

There is one thing to note here. If your Terms.java is in a default package, there is not a way to do a static import on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that they refer to [static import](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Example:

```
import static mypackage.Term.*;
```

This will enable you to use your code like:

```
public void doSomething(Term term)
{
    if (NET_30_DAYS.equals(term))
    {
        ...
    }
    else if ...
}
```